# Python regex - matching regex in Cisco ASA config

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following config from a Cisco ASA:

```
access-list OUTSIDE extended permit tcp any object O-10.1.2.230 eq 9091  
access-list OUTSIDE extended permit tcp any object O-10.1.2.241 eq pptp
```

I want the result to look like this in a list or CSV format:

```
rule number, permit/deny, protocol, source IP, source port, des ip, des port.

1, permit, tcp, any, any, 10.1.2.230, 9091  
2, permit, tcp, any, any, 10.1.2.241, pptp
```

for line in open("file.txt"):
    if "access-list" in line:
        print line.split()

print type(line)

Thanks!

Comment: Is the format always like that? I mean are there always spaces delimiting each field?

Comment: If the format will be same always, then you don't require regex. Just split on basis of space and read on the index basis.

Comment: so I am opening a file with a complete firewall configuration. Then I need to search for all lines that start with "access-list". I then just need to return this value as a list and I can display on the index like you said. I assume I still need regex to do the searching?

Comment: @Adrian Tolley : Just check word "access-list" in each line while reading file line by line. ( if "access-list in line:). If present split and get required values and write is to csv.

Comment: I have data displayed now as ['access-list', 'OUTSIDE' etc] but when I do a print type(line) it show is as a str and not a list. Any ideas here?

Comment: @Adrian Tolley - Please paste your code in question. Will be more helpful.

Comment: for line in open("file.txt"):
    if "access-list" in line:    
        print line.split()    

print type(line)

Comment: @Adrian Tolley - Please check below answer.

Comment: @Adrian Tolley - Please let me know if below answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this is useful.

```
import csv
import sys
#Open both files and get handles.
config_file = open("out.txt" ,'r')
csv_file = open("result.csv",'w')
#
try:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    #Write titles in csv file
    csv_head_list = ['rule number', 'permit/deny', 'protocol', 'source IP', 'source port', 'des ip', 'des port']
    writer.writerow( csv_head_list )
    rule_num = 0
    #Read file line by line
    for line in config_file.readlines():
        line=line.strip()
        #Check "access-list" in line
        if "access-list" in line:
            tmp_list = line.split()
            rule_num = rule_num + 1
            permit_deny = str(tmp_list[3])
            protocol = str(tmp_list[4])
            src_ip = src_port = str(tmp_list[5])
            des_ip = str(tmp_list[7]).replace("O-",'')
            des_port = str(tmp_list[9])
            #Write data in csv file
            csv_data_list =[rule_num, permit_deny, protocol, src_ip, src_port, des_ip, des_port]

            writer.writerow( csv_data_list)
            csv_data_list = []
except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
finally:
    config_file.close()
    csv_file.close()
```